# Using a python for loop to print numbers from a list which are not in order of their index

Tags: python

I have a little query I'm currently trying to use a for loop to print the numbers in my list, I would like to print several numbers which are next to each other, but then I would also like to print several numbers which are further down the list. My code is below what I would like to do is print the numbers 51 and 52 as well as printing the numbers 56 and 57. Is it possible to do this within one loop or will I need to create another on?

```
Test = [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62]


for i in range (1,3), (6, 8): 
    print (Test[i])
```

Comment: `range (1,3), (6, 8)` becomes roughly `([1, 2], (6, 8))`.

Comment: `range` produces continuous ranges with no gaps. `for i in (1,2,6,7):` will do what you want.

Comment: Can you give an example for what you expected output?

Answer (score 2):

```py
Test = [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62]

indices = (1, 2, 6, 7)

for i in indices: 
    print(Test[i])

>>>51 52 56, 57 (on separate lines, of course)
```

If you always want to print in pairs, you can only specify the first element's index and print twice in the loop:

```py
Test = [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62]

indices = (1, 6)

for i in indices: 
    print(Test[i])
    print(Test[i+1])

>>>51 52 56, 57 (on separate lines, of course)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zd4E.png)

```
Test = [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62]


for i in range (1,3): 
    print (Test[i])

for i in range (6, 8): 
    print (Test[i])
```